# Elder Scroll Online System Error

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I cannot start the game.

eso.exe - System Error.
"The program can't start because D3DCOMPILER_43.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

On Windows 7 64 bit. I tried to (re)install DirectX (dxwebsetup.exe from http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/1/1718CCC4-6315-4D8E-9543-8E28A4E18C4C/dxwebsetup.exe), still the error message remains.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the DirectX setup did not finished. I re-run it, and Elder Scrolls Online Started.